The use of starred sectioning commands and document structure
When Leslie Lamport developed LaTeX his main objective was to separate the structure from presentation. This he achieved admirably perhaps with the exception of tabulars. In this respect commands like \section come in two flavours, a starred version and an unstarred version.
A starred version never prints a number or writes the heading in the toc, except when used internally by LaTeX in macros.
Typographical tradition sets headings in frontmatter and backmatter generally unnumbered and the level of headings included in the ToC, in published books, varies from  book to book.
LaTeX solves this by the use of tocdepth. It also offers an additional counter
\secnumdepth which switches numbering off for headings greater than this counter.
This bring me to the question. IMHO if one wants to retain the central idea of a structured document the star version of a heading has no meaning as a user command, writing for example the code below in mainmatter:
section{First Section}
section*{Second section}
section{Third section}

is wrong as section* imparts no semantic or structured meaning in this respect. It is just a misuse of an internal command as a user-command. In brand new classes in a situation like the code above an error or warning should be issued and two versions of the<heading> should be provided in for use in commands writing ToCs to write numbered of unumbered headings, based on booleans detecting frontmatter, mainmatter or backmatter and one could throw appendix in this as well  If Templates were not so unloved maybe the<heading> should be a template with two instances or alternatively the headings could be templates. Are there instances where the use of a starred version of a command can be considered a  user command?
** Edit: removed the word legitimate to make the question clearer**

I think this is really an opinion discussion and doesn't fit the site format

@DavidCarlisle   I humbly disagree. The bold two lines at the end are very specific.

Sure there is no harm in disagreeing that's why the site works on voting (although actually I haven't voted so far) but the last bold line doesn't change the status, different people can consider different things as legitimate, that is more or less by definition an "opinion based" question.

Like @DavidCarlisle, I'd say this is very much opinion-based - to me \section* is simply a short version of some longer semantic \section[<various-keyvals-that-control-appearance>]{<Title>}, at least conceptually. (With the changes we are making in the kernel, that may well become the reality.)

@JosephWright  Thanks. I wrote the word legitimate to mean reasonable and valid (Cambridge dict.).  I removed it to make the question non-opinion based.  I will delete the question in the morning whatever the outcome.

I normally do not use the starred version on the user level.

is the objection specifically to starred sectioning commands? you also mention tabular, but I'm not sure about the connection?

@cfr I had to write some background info to explain my thinking. I mentioned that Lamport achieved the structure except for tabulars, as they normally have a head and a body made of rows which are made of cells etc. If you familiar with web development an css, they have achieved it.

You could obviously use some different way of marking up document divisions which shouldn't be numbered, but you would need to add additional infrastructure to create a framework with the same degree of flexibility. Unnumbered chapters are not only found in \frontmatter and backmatter. They are also common between major sections of books, for example. This is extremely common in anthologies, at least in my discipline, because editors frequently sub-divide books into smaller chunks which group chapters together according to some criterion. So you might have something like
\title{The Evolution of Books}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
\chatper*{Introduction}
\part{Ancient Writings}
\chapter*{Books of Stone}
\chapter{Roman Tablets}
\chapter{Deciphering Stones}
\dots
\part{The Printing Press}
\chapter*{Books for the Many}
\chapter{Gutenberg's Revolution}
\dots
\backmatter
\chapter*{Epilogue}
\dots

You could drop the stars in the \frontmatter and \mainmatter but, without starred forms, you'd need to develop alternative markup for the other starred cases and that markup might or might not fit different use cases semantically.
It's also not always clear whether divisions should or shouldn't be numbered. Lots of anthologies number the introduction as chapter 1, even though it is grouped as part of the \frontmatter and multiple appendices typically require labels of some kind.
So to accommodate the range of layouts found in the real world, you do need starred forms of document divisions or some equivalent. Stars have the virtue of simplicity and at least don't require people to mark things up in ways which are semantically wrong, even if they don't provide semantic markup.
The real issue with the document divisions, imho, is \paragraph(*) and \subparagraph(*) where the naming is at odds with the function and general confusion ensues. Exchanging stars for something which didn't fit the full range of use cases might simply repeat that mistake.
If we look beyond book, yet further complications arise. Articles don't typically have front matter or back matter - at least, these terms aren't usually applied to them - but they often have unnumbered sections for acknowledgements, references etc. Again, you could obviously provide alternative markup, but article is used for a great variety of document types and that makes the names of macros or environments problematic. Almost inevitably some uses would require anti-semantic markup, which is very confusing for users.
Ideally, too, it should be possible to change the document class without changing the markup. In reality, this is rarely the case even with the standard classes. On the other hand, deliberately designing new classes which don't recognise common macros in the standard classes imposes an additional burden. It is not clear to me any perceived benefits are worth the costs. Certainly it seems legitimate for a class author to come to a different conclusion from yours.

In your example, I would do \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} And use chapter{} in frontmatter, as you seem to only need the Part numbered. This is what I was objecting  \chapter*{Books for the Many} \chapter{Gutenberg's Revolution}    what meaning do you want to impart to your readers with these? There was never any suggestion to change the mark-up, only the suggestion that is wrong to mix numbered and unumbered sections in the maimatter of a book and similarly for articles. In an anthology, I would number only  the main division in your case Part,maybe calling \partname  something else ...

I can understand why whoever wrote the structure wrote it the way of your example, as I had the same problem like he did. Sometimes you want to explain what the part is about, maybe a page or two, in this case I would rather redesign the Part to accommodate some text. Many textbooks do this.

@yannisl well, that is not how anthologies in my discipline are usually arranged. typically, there's a chapter at the start of each \part (sometimes there is nothing, but often) without a number. then all the other chapters in that part get numbers. this is very, very common, even if you wouldn't do it this way. of course, you could have some other macro for the unnumbered ones, but you definitely need it. some also have an unnumbered chapter at the end of each part providing, say, further reading suggestions.

Thanks this was actually the crux of my question if there are cases where the star heading is a user command. The Further reading suggestions if you use BiblaTeX  is very semantic though as it defines its own heading (just uses internally section* or chapter*)  which you provide it as an option in the printbibliography. If you dont mind me asking what field are you working with? I would love to see some examples of anthologies.

Here  is a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/13MvFT-WJsqINdXSbvrtiZQbV2mo6ykpo/view?usp=sharing    with a published anthology from  Economic Freedom and
Interventionism
An Anthology of Articles and Essays   Von Mises. Screen capture mine.

@yannisl Philosophy.
